# Strapi V4 Error: Can't resolve '@strapi/design-system/themes'

Tags: node.js, npm, strapi

I'm trying to run the new Strapi version 4 application. But it returns this error.
Is there any bug in new strapi v4? or I'm doing wrong anything?
I'm using strapi official guide to start a new project

installation command `npx create-strapi-app@latest molla-admin`.

NodeJS v16

Windows 11

Error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@strapi/design-system/themes' in 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\molla-admin\.cache\admin\src'
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\molla-<anonymous>:10:1)
```

You might be thinking `@strapi/design-system` package is missing right?  After that, I also tried to install both `@strapi/design-system` and `@strapi/design-system/themes` npm package
Still, it doesn't work. It returns a new error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@strapi/icons/CarretDown' in 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\testing\strapi-v4-app\node_modules\@strapi\helper-plugin\build'
```

Should I go on for the next missing Module?

Answer (score 8):

For me the issue was solved by installing @strapi/design-system (Node: v14.15.5, npm: 8.1.3)

```
npm install @strapi/design-system
```

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. It returns a new error. I updated my question you can see the error.

Answer (score 5):

```
Node version : 14.18.1
Npm version : 6.14.15
OS : Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

Steps I followed:

> (I read somewhere that the latest version of node isnt working and
> someone mentioned using the 14.18.1 version)

1. Downgraded NPM to use the 14.18.1 version and not the latest.
2. `npm run build` on the strapi project. ***This gave an error that its
   missing @strapi/design-system.***
3. `npm install @strapi/design-system`, ***you get another error that its missing @strapi/icons***
4. `npm install @strapi/icons` . ***After this step there was an error relating to JSX scritps something to do with reactjs. So, in the next step , I updated Reactjs***
5. `npm install --save react@latest`
6. `npm run build` ***again and this time SUCCESS!!***

The strapi team should mention the issues on their homepage rather that making new users go through hoops to get it working. They need to make it clear that you can run into issues when using certain version of Node etc. As someone mentioned that they are aware of the issue yet no information in the homepage where new users visit to try it out. It should've been placed as a BANNER at the top in BOLD TEXT.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11640) and they are working on a fix.
You have to use [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) in the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this bug is related to using Node v16. To get around the bug, I first ran:

```
nvm use 14.18.1
```

Afterwards, running the following resulted in successful compilation:

```
npm run build -- --clean
```

**No need to attempt installation of @strapi/design-system.**

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was using Node v16. There was a message somewhere in my troubleshooting that you have to use A Node `version >=10.X.X.X and <=14.X.X.X`
I used NVM(Node Version Manager) to switch to 14.17.6 and it works

Comment: Thanks for your information. I also tried with node V14. The error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

following solution worked for me:

```
yarn add @strapi/design-system
yarn add @strapi/icons
```

work on windows and ubuntu

node v14.15.0

yarn 1.22.17

npm  6.14.8

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @strapi/design-system`

solution worked for me.

node 16.13.1

npm 8.1.4

macOS 12.0.1 on M1Max